# Is there any sort of "time handler" in c#?

Tags: c#, time, timer, handler

I want a program that runs continually and monitors the time constantly. When it's 15:30 PM (just as an example) it will execute Console.Beep() (just another example). Any thoughts on how to do this? Yes I searched the internet, and I found some MSDN stuff about time management but never anything on how to keep listening for certain times so to speak.

Comment: If you don't want to roll your own, look at quartz.net:  http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Never thought it was, I just got stuck here and I thought someone might know something about this subject.

Comment: @user1007059 Same basic difference.

Comment: 15:30 PM is nonsense.  15:30 or 3:30 PM make sense.

Comment: Yes yes I know I was just in a hurry typing this and all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but it's a beginning. The method is supposed to loop forever and beep whenever the time is 15:30.

```
static void BeepWhen1530()
{
  var alarmTime = new TimeSpan(15, 30, 00);
  while (true)
  {
    var clock = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    if (clock >= alarmTime && clock < alarmTime + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0))
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Alarm: BEEP!");
      Console.Beep();

      // wait for two minutes so the alarm won't go off again until tomorrow
      Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2.0));
    }

    // wait some time so we won't consume too much cpu cycles
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500.0));
  }
}
```